How is the IV/Nonce determined in OFB mode? - SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)
I am doing some research in different methods of encryption for SQLite databases. One of the databases I have is AES-256 OFB encrypted with SEE (https://sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki). Unfortunately, I couldn't find much information about it's implementation.
I know the decryption key, the data is encrypted in pages (4096 bytes) and the nonce (which is used for the IV) can be either 4, 12 or 32.
When the nonce is 12, working out the IV is simple: page number (4 bytes) + (nonce) reserved bytes at the end of the page (12 bytes) = 16 bytes
However, if the nonce is 4 or 32 this formula doesn't work :(
Does anyone know if there is some kind of padding added to the IV if it's not 16 bytes?

Download and check? https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/index.wiki . Probably filled with zero or hashed directly..
